# Aliasing in React Native Vector Icons on iPhone XR

Tags: iphone, react-native, react-native-vector-icons

### Environment

iPhone XR 
React Native 0.59.9
React Native Vector Icons 6.5.0

### Description

using `import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/Ionicons';`

even if I return `<Icon />` with no parameters, the icon is blurred/aliased. 
Changing the size and css doesn't change anything.
I couldn't find anything in the docs about this so any guidance is very very appreciated :)

Here's a screenshot of what I'm talking about

[image: Screen Shot 2019-06-07 at 10 42 24 AM]
[image: Screen Shot 2019-06-07 at 10 42 06 AM]

This doesn't happen in any other iPhone,